# Android + Phonegap + Bluetooth readings

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins, rfid

I have just finished my app using: https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin as a plugin for my phonegap over android application. Now i am testing it and turns out that the readings i am performing with a RFID stick scanner are not always the same.
Sometimes i get readings like this from the same tag:

```
FDXB=4712000000400E018000000000
```

This is okay, but sometimes i am just getting

```
:FD
```

and then immediately it comes a new data with the rest of the string:

```
XB=4712000000400E018000000000
```

is this a hardware issue?

Comment: I have an antenna rfid and want to connect to my android via usb.
which plugin you recommend?

Comment: @Tbseven the linked plugin worked for me, except for the issue i described above, i never was abled to fix it